# Matlab programming code

Tags: matlab

I wrote a program on Matlab that checks how many numbers are divisable by 2 starting from 1 to integer N (that is set by the user)

Here's my code:

```
num=input('Please enter a number');
count=0;

while (num>=0);

if  mod(num,2)==0;
    count=count+1;
end
  num=num-1;

end

disp(count)
```

I've tried to run this code but it doesn't output anything. I hope someone can help me figure out what is wrong it Please note that we haven't studied it in school, I just read online and tried to write something on my own.

Comment: I suggest you not use `if  mod(num,2)==0` you could try some simpler things like `if num/2 == floor(num/2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see many logical errors in your code. To begin with you are checking if `num` is divisible by `10`, not `2`. Also you should decrement `num` regardless if it passes the if condition, if you want to check the next number. Finally you say you want to check numbers ranging `1 to N` but your while loop actually checks numbers `0 to N`, due to the `>=` condition.

From a syntactical point of view: if's and while's (and for's) should not have a trailing semicolon after them.

So maybe something like this could be closer to what you are asking, albeit I still don't know if I fully understand your problem.

```matlab
% Ask for user input
num = input('Please enter a number');

count = 0;
while (num > 0)
    % Check for divisibility
    if  mod (num, 2) == 0
        count = count + 1;
    end

    % Decrement number
    num = num - 1;
end

% Display the count -- writing the variable name without an ending semicolon ';' causes Matlab to output the variable content
count
```

Comment: I think you have to change it a bit. `num = 20` gives `count = 11`, which should be `10`.

Comment: @kamtal while (num >= 0) allows the zero ;-)

Comment: @Kamtal: `mod(2, 0)` gives `0`. It all depends on what the OP is looking for. ;)

Comment: because he mentioned "from `1` to `N`". Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Kamtal That's actually a good point I totally disregarded. Will correct it immediately. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize I had %10 instead of %2. I have one more question please, do the number of spaces effect the code I write? Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @NoorAIH In Matlab absolutely not. You should read a few tutorials on the internet, for you own sake. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No need in loop, use Matlab the way it was designed for

```
num = input('Please enter a number ');
count = sum(mod(1 : num, 2) == 0);
disp(count);
```

Comment: Good one. But I think he is a beginner and he is after some simple code to learn.

Comment: I didn't know that I can actually do all that in 3 steps. I'm new to Matlab. Looks very efficient, thanks a lot!

Comment: @NoorAIH the way you are trying to write is generic for the most of the programming languages, it does not have any specifics of Matlab.